# .jar file not laoding images while opening from different folder

Tags: java, image, swing, jar

I made a .jar file in Netbeans which works properly in Netbeans but when I placed the jar file in another folder from dist folder, then the jar doesn't load the images, what can I do now?

Comment: Is the image stored inside the JAR, or in the folder containing the JAR?  How are you loading the image?

Comment: I'm loading images like : ImageIcon ic1=new ImageIcon("pic/welcome.jpg");   inside project folder there is a folder named pic containing images..

Comment: And does that folder and file exist in the new folder location?

Comment: BTW, I highly recommend storing the image inside the JAR and using `Class.getResource()`.

Comment: yeah, when I try to replace the jar file from project/dist folder to another remote folder, it doesn't load images , but if i keep the images inside the same folder it works,,, how can I keep jar file alone? not with images?

Comment: Do what I recommended.  Put the images inside the JAR file and use `Class.getResource()`.  That is usually best practice.  That enables you to move only one resource (the JAR file) instead of many (the JAR file and all its supporting images).

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You are loading images from the `JAR` then you have to load them as `Resource`

```
ImageIcon ic1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pic/welcome.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had troubles with getResource() inside a jar, but always have success when getting the resource as a stream.

```
ImageIcon ic1 = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pic/welcome.jpg")))
```